# Meshlab Raster registration using mutual information

Tags: meshlab

i am using Meshlab to map a series of photos on a scanned mesh, but i never obtain a perfect alignment of images on the mesh.

I would to ask if the raster alignment in Meshlab can take care of distortion parameters of lens...
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Show your effort here by showing your code, so other people know what's wrong in your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using photogrammetry software to obtain a scan, you should be able to save the camera positions obtained from the scan, and import them in MeshLab.

Using your photogrammetry software, you can choose to save the scan project as a bundle.out file (alternatively, an .nvm file). This file will contain all the camera positions.

Next, open MeshLab, and as the first thing, choose file -> open project... 
Then, choose the bundle.out file as well as the bundle.list file. Make sure the list file is in the same folder as your rasters (images used to obtain the scan).

Now, import your 3D model.

If you click the "Show current raster mode" button, you will see the raster. If you scroll up and down, you will be able to check if the image is aligned to your model.

If any image is not aligned, uncheck it in the image list in the bottom right.

Next, go to filters -> texture -> "Parameterization + texturing from registered rasters"

Choose the texture size, (e.g. 1024, 2048 etc)  choose texture name, and click apply.

If all steps are successful, you should have a fully textured model.